# Core Data Binary Data Allow External Storage

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am storage image into Core Data as an external storage as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

The problem is when I retrieve the couponImage property I never get nil even if I don't save any couponImage. The coupon Image is of type NSData?. When I print it on the console it prints the following:

```
External Resource path = nil    // This is where there is no image 

External Resource path = EDCS-EDAS-23eD-EDRF-EWQ3-234F
```

My question is how do you differentiate between an image which does not exist vs image which does exist.

Comment: You can always add another boolean attribute although I'm not sure if it's the correct way to approach this.

Comment: That is the route I took.